# Vue.js pop a nested object from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, multidimensional-array

Working on a quick dashboard and I want to remove the second Object from `departments_by_dept_emp`. How would this be best achievable with Vue?

HTML

```
<tbody id="rows" v-for="result in results">
   <tr>
     <td>{{ result.first_name }} {{ result.last_name }}</td>
     <td v-for="department in result.departments_by_dept_emp">{{ department.dept_name }}</td>
     <td>{{ result.hire_date }}</td>
     <td>{{ result.birth_date }}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

JavaScript

```
   {
   "emp_no": 10010,
      "birth_date": "1963-06-01",
      "first_name": "Duangkaew",
      "last_name": "Piveteau",
      "gender": "F",
      "hire_date": "1989-08-24",
      "departments_by_dept_emp": [
        {
          "dept_no": "d004",
          "dept_name": "Production"
        },
        {
          "dept_no": "d006",
          "dept_name": "Quality Management"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Axios call getting the data is stored in an empty array

```
data () {
    return {
      results: [],
    }
}
```

Axios call

```
getData() {
      this.loading = true

      axios.get('https://url', { 'headers': { 'Api-Key': '' } })
          .then(response => {
            this.results = response.data.resource
            this.next = response.data.meta.next
            this.loading = false
            console.log(response.data.resource)
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
          })
      }
```

So from the example, essentially I only want the Production department name and remove Quality Management from my table. I do not believe slice() will do the trick as it will only clone one dimension. Also, anything like splice() or findIndex I receive the error "Cannot read property '{example}' of undefined""

Comment: Hi, would it be possible to provide examples of what you have already tried?, otherwise it looks like you are trying to get people to write code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to display an element from an array you can pass the index of the element to display

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    results:  [{
      "emp_no": 10010,
      "birth_date": "1963-06-01",
      "first_name": "Duangkaew",
      "last_name": "Piveteau",
      "gender": "F",
      "hire_date": "1989-08-24",
      "departments_by_dept_emp": [
        {
          "dept_no": "d004",
          "dept_name": "Production"
        },
        {
          "dept_no": "d006",
          "dept_name": "Quality Management"
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tbody id="rows" >
      <tr v-for="result in results">
        <td>{{ result.first_name }} {{ result.last_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ result.departments_by_dept_emp[0].dept_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ result.hire_date }}</td>
        <td>{{ result.birth_date }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since vue.js data objects are simply javascript objects, it should be possible to use array.pop().

You should be able to add a function like this to your methods block:

```
popDept: function() {
   return this.departments_by_dept_emp.pop();
},
```

This function will both remove the department from the list, and return it.

Comment: Thank you, this was originally the idea. This will not work as `this.departments_by_dept_emp` does not exist by the way I am storing the results from my axios call like so 
`data () {
    return {
      results: []
}
}`

Comment: Ah I see, would you mind including the code for the axios call in the question so that we can provide a better answer?

Answer (score 0):

At risk of looking like writing some code for you...

Vue is a javascript framework so you can write functions in plain javascript to find an item in an array and then remove it. So in your template where you iterate through `department.dept_name` you could add a click listener, `@click="removeElement(department.dept_name)"`

Then in your script section:

```
export default {
data: () => ({
  results: {
  "emp_no": 10010,
     "birth_date": "1963-06-01",
     "first_name": "Duangkaew",
     "last_name": "Piveteau",
     "gender": "F",
     "hire_date": "1989-08-24",
     "departments_by_dept_emp": [
       {
         "dept_no": "d004",
         "dept_name": "Production"
       },
       {
         "dept_no": "d006",
         "dept_name": "Quality Management"
       }
     ]
   }
}),
methods: {
  removeElement(x) {
    var ind = this.results.departments_by_dept_emp.findIndex(n => n.dept_name === x)  
    this.results.departments_by_dept_emp.splice(ind, 1)
}
```

That will remove the object from the array and leave the rest as is.